# SQL dynamic WHERE clause for every row

Tags: sql

I need your expertise and guidance to understand the approach I should use to solve the task below. I have skimmed through existing answers but have not found good matches (unless they were there but they required extensive SQL knowledge and experience)

**TASK**

calculate total sales forecast per product for a period of time (from beginning of sales until end of end sales).

**DATA**

Table_1: Product - Calendar Week - Sales Forecast

Table_2: Product - Sales Start (Date_1, Individual for every product)

Table_3: Product - Sales End (Date_2, Individual for every product )

**SOLUTION**

My initial thought was to use simple WHERE BETWEEN clause but SQL crashes every time I execute the

```
    SELECT
    Product,
    SUM(Sales_Forecast) 
    FROM Table_1 as T1
    LEFT JOIN Table_2 as T2
    ON T1.Product=T2.Product.
    LEFT JOIN Table_3 as T3
    ON T1.Product=T3.Product 
    WHERE T1.Calender_week BETWEEN T2.Sales_Start AND T3.Sales_End
    GROUP BY Product
```

Thus the time period I am looking for is not static and it varies depending on a product and its start and end date of sales.

How should I better approach this task?

Thanks in advance,
f

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause after the WHERE clause.

Comment: And a comma between the selected fields

Comment: And no fullstop after Product.

Comment: I doubt your query will execute.

Comment: I have added GROUP BY clause and a comma and also removed fullstop from this example above but those correct in the original text (sorry for mistype). I truly believe it is about the logic/approach. Any ideas?:) Maybe there are any work around's?)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DB you are using. Date functions are often DB-specific so without knowing which DB you are using it is impossible to know if a specific solution will work for you.

Also, please can you provide some sample data and the table definitions? In particular, how is your "Calendar Week" value being stored?